How can I get the Members joining my Channel correctly in Python?
I have a Telegram Channel and 3 days ago I wanted to add an Invite counter to it so if peopler invite their friends, they get something or can participate in certain giveaways.
So I tried it and I started it with Invite Links sent from a bot.
So the bot makes an extra invite Link for every user sending /start to the bot and if somebody joins using this Link the person they got the Link from would get +1 invite.
But sadly I failed with counting the people that joined through the Links.
Telegram Channel Invite
My friend joined using this Link but in the manage Channel  ---> Invite Links it says 0 joins.
So after that didnt work I tried it with annother method.
referral_link = f"https://t.me/{context.bot.username}?start={unique_code}"
This time I tried this:
When a user sends /create they should get this type of Link and if somebody clicks on it the bot knows who gave it to them.
But they would still have to join the channel and I dont know how to find out if they actually did and how to connect it to my bot so yes I dont know anymore what to do.
Thanks for help!
I put everything I tried in the explanation above
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated
I tried using this but it didnt really work for me
